# How to handle PA 529 if the actual rent is more than COA?

Tags: united-states, withdrawal, 529-plan

My child is going to live off-campus and pay rent more than COA rent suggested by the college.

1. Can I withdraw the COA rent amount from 529 and show the actual rent paid (which is way more) as proof?
2. Can I withdraw rent money every month or should I do it after one semester?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. You can withdraw up to the off-campus COA amount.
   https://www.savingforcollege.com/article/can-you-use-a-529-plan-to-pay-for-room-and-board
2. Either method is fine, but "be sure to take the distribution in the same year that the qualified expense was paid"
   https://www.savingforcollege.com/article/using-your-529-plan-to-pay-for-room-and-board